# FTP subfolder list

Tags: c#, ftp

I have a ftp path `ftp://10.23.XX.XX/IN` and inside that `IN` folder I have ten more folders, which are `ES`, `US`,`UK` etc. In C# I want to read the folder names only and not the files inside. Could you please let me know how to do that?

Also, I have used many more sites where its telling me to go for `GetResponseStream` but I am not able to find correct code to get directories.

The code I tried to use is below:

```
FtpWebRequest request = (FtpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("ftp://10.23.xx.xx/IN");
         request.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("ABC", "ABC");
         //request.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.PrintWorkingDirectory.All<request.>;
         // request.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.ListDirectory;
         request.Proxy = null ;
         using (FtpWebResponse response = (FtpWebResponse)request.GetResponse()){}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use it that way I used to do that:

```
    request.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.ListDirectoryDetails;
    FtpWebResponse response = request.GetResponse() as FtpWebResponse;
    Stream responseStream = response.GetResponseStream();
    StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(responseStream);
    while ((sSource = reader.ReadLine()) != null)
            {something}
```

But I strongly sugget to use 3rd party lib like edtFTPnet.dll where you will do what you need as simply as:

```
FTPFile[] elementy = ftpConnection1.GetFileInfos();
foreach (FTPFile elem in elementy)
{
  if (elem.Dir)//true if item is Directory
   {
//something
    }
 }
```

Comment: `{something}` ? whats this? how could one know its a directory or file